# Zip csv file in Python without merging columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I need to output a csv file in python, and as the file is too large, I use the package 'zipfile' to zip it. However, when the csv file is outputed and unzipped, the columns merged......

The code is like:

```
    for i in dealers:
        data_1=data_dealer[data_dealer['DEALER_ID']==i]
        data=data_1.to_string(index=False, header=True).encode("utf_8_sig")
        azip=zipfile.Zipfile('data%s.zip'%i,mode='w')
        azip.writestr('data%s.csv'%i,data=data,compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        azip.close()
```

the csv was originally like (separated by comma):

```
a,1600,2018,NaN,......
```

now there's only one column, or separated by space:

```
a 1600 2018 NaN ......
```

Anyone knows how to zip a csv in Python without merging the columns?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the columns are *merged*"? Can you provide an example? I find it hard to believe that zipping and unzipping will modify the file's content. See [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DeepSpace thank you, I've provided a simple example (which really happened......)

Comment: @Deanna we will need to see some code

Comment: @DeepSpace code updated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using `data = data1.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf_8_sig')` instead of `to_string`. Is the encode necessary?

Answer (score 0):

By using Pandas `to_string()` function, you were creating a textual fixed column width table output suitable for displaying on a console. You wanted though to create a CSV output with `,` delimiters between the columns. As such you need to use the `to_csv()` function. If a filename is not given to the function, it returns the whole table as a string. This could then be passed using `writestr()`:

```
for i in dealers:
    data_1 = data_dealer[data_dealer['DEALER_ID']==i]
    data = data_1.to_csv(index=False, header=True).encode("utf_8_sig")
    azip = zipfile.Zipfile('data{}.zip'.format(i), mode='w')
    azip.writestr('data{}.csv'.format(i), data=data, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    azip.close()
```